# How to set Subversion properties with git-svn

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, collaboration

Is there a way to set subversion properties on a git repository that was created by git-svn?

In my case, I want to edit the version of `svn:external`, `svn:ignore` and
`svn:executable`.

However, the only way to do so seems to involve a check-out with the subversion client. Is there a way to edit svn properties without having to check out the repository twice (one time for git and one time with svn for the properties)?

Comment: Note `git svn propset` is supported with Git 2.3.0 (February 2015): see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28268059/6309).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note: git 2.3.0 (February 2015) supports proset with [`git svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).
See [commit 83c9433](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83c9433e679635f8fbf8961081ea3581c93ca778) by [Alfred Perlstein (`splbio`)](https://github.com/splbio):

> #### `git-svn`: support for `git-svn propset`
>
> This change allows `git-svn` to support setting subversion properties.
>
> It is useful for manually setting properties when committing to a subversion repo that *requires* properties to be set without requiring moving your changeset to separate subversion checkout in order to set props.
>
> There is a nit to point out: **the code does not support adding props unless there are also content changes to the files as well**.
> This is demonstrated in the testcase.

So, as seen in [`t/t9148-git-svn-propset.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/83c9433e679635f8fbf8961081ea3581c93ca778/t/t9148-git-svn-propset.sh), this now works:

```
git svn propset "$1" "$2" "$file" 
# like
git svn propset "svn:keywords" "FreeBSD=%H" "foo"
```

Answer (score 17):

`git-svn` does not support Subversion properties. When I run into this problem, I usually end up having two checkouts.

This is mentioned in the [`git-svn`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-svn.html#_bugs) documentation under BUGS:

> We ignore all SVN properties except svn:executable. Any unhandled properties are logged to `$GIT_DIR/svn/<refname>/unhandled.log`

Comment: This is not the answer I hoped for - but I guess I have to accept it.

Comment: You don't need to have a Subversion checkout to set properties in a repository.  You can set them straight in the repository using `svn.exe` or using TortoiseSVN's `Repo-browser`.

Comment: This answer is no longer true, see VonC's answer instead

Answer (score 5):

Started working on a patch to support `git svn propset` here: [git svn propset support](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=125259772625008&w=2)

Comment: Thank You, David.
I look forward to seeing this functionality in the next release version.

Comment: Yes; unfortunately my patch would have taken lots of reworking to get accepted, and I've moved away from using `git svn` in its standard form so am not intending to keep developing this...

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, just clone your SVN repository with [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). It translates svn:executable, svn:externals and svn:ignore to executable, .gitsvnextmodules and .gitignore. So you can modify them and push back that will result in corresponding properties modification.

If you have an access to your SVN server you may install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into it. It translates svn:executable and svn:ignore on the server side providing a Git interface to your SVN repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can also used [svnmucc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnmucc.re.html), in case you don't want to have a whole svn checkout just to set props (my remote repo is really big).

Here's my command for adding a line to svn:ignore, replace URL, DIR, and VALUE.

```
svnmucc -U URL propset svn:ignore "`git svn propget svn:ignore DIR; echo VALUE`" DIR
```

Comment: I like this, but I also modified to get the URL automatically: `svnmucc -U "$(git svn info | egrep '^URL\:' | cut -d' ' -f2-)" propset svn:global-ignores PATTERN DIRECTORY` (`.` for DIRECTORY as example).