# How do I update .svn info from out-of-band work area update?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn

Let's say I update my working copy out-of-band (*details below) - how do I have TortoiseSVN check the *state* of the working area against the server HEAD and update the local 'revision' **info** *without having to transfer all the files* (again) from the server? Right now my workflow is essentially to roll back the out-of-band updates, then do the SVN update (which re-transfers all of the files even though I already 'have them' locally) - I'd prefer to let the out-of-band updates stay and just have Tortoise detect that the files do, in fact, match the server...

---

*Details: This could be simply 'I get a zip file from my coworker with the latest changes (perhaps because that's faster than stupid-slow SVN...)', so I've intentionally abstracted the actual how from the question itself, but here are the details of my particular use-case.

I use `git-svn` to interact with a svn repo, but [`git-svn` doesn't support Subversion properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1271487), or at least not well - I tried, but remember there being some issues (possibly the requirement to update the file as well, as I want to adjust `svn:global-ignores` at the top level...). One way to handle that, as suggested in the linked answer, is to have a completely separate svn checkout to interact with those properties. This seems wasteful and even slower, so I set up my local `git-svn` clone to a directory called `trunk` and put that in the SVN checkout. Now I can get both to be 'happy' with some management and run ~updates from either direction - there are definitely some 'gotchas', but it's mostly manageable until we transition to git fully (soon).

I prefer to interact with git (or `git-svn` as applicable) as much as possible, so I usually run a `git svn rebase`, which pulls in incremental updates from the server. If I want to update the SVN side (e.g. so I can do a straight SVN commit to adjust *just* properties), I have to roll back the git repo to the local SVN HEAD and ask SVN to update the repo, which then pulls down all the files again and is just annoying. I'd like to just run `git svn rebase`, and then have TortoiseSVN confirm that the new working copy matches the server HEAD.

My first attempt was to leave the git-svn HEAD in place and run `svn update --accept=working` so it would just mark issues as resolved (since, uh, the HEAD *did* match - "*trust me*, SVN..."), but that apparently caused major issues in my SVN side when I tried to create an SVN commit the next time - it *did not* know what was going on...

Comment: The answer to the generic question is that you don't (normally) need to do anything special. TortoiseSVN doesn't require you to register external changes manually, being moves and renames possibly the only exception (and even then you can use TortoiseSVN to fix them afterwards). I suspect your problems come from your very specific setup involving git (I can't give advice about that).

Comment: I can't imagine how the `git-svn` update would be different to TortoiseSVN than, say, transferring files from a coworker with a zip file - the files themselves _may_ have changed, or they may not; likewise, timestamps _may_ have changed (/let's say _probably_), but a changed timestamp doesn't necessarily mean a different file - so I want Tortoise to check the _contents_ of the files before considering them all out-of-date... cause they match what's on the server, just not what Tortoise knows about locally...